# C/C++ Remote Compilation, local Debug Session with ELF (Embedded, Cortex-M)

Tags: c++, c, eclipse

I do a lot of coding in C/C++ on my notebook. Unfortunately, the dual core has its limits when it comes to compilation, which I do a lot. but the advantage is that I'm mobile and I can carry my debugger (usb j-link) around (and no, the ethernet-j-link option is too expensive).

I do have a server with 24 cores. I would like to use the server for compilation and then copy the compiled files (mainly the ELF) over to my local machine for debugging.

Both machines use Ubuntu (Ubuntu Budgie for the notebook, Ubuntu Server for the server).

Sadly, the Eclipse GDB (Atollic 8.1) is no longer able to map the binary addresses to my source files in the graphical debugger (understandably).

I was wondering how the graphical debugger is possible to map addresses to the text (src).
Is this path information within the ELF file? If so, how can I correct it so the remote-compiled-binary is able to debug-run on my notebook?

Comment: 1. Are you sure you do not strip the binaries while copying? 2. Have you tried to use same paths to repository at both computers?

Comment: You could try to use distcc

Comment: @max630 i did verify with md5, is the same file. i did not try to use the same path, good idea. will do so. thank you. Is is difficult for an embedded software engineer with a bit of knowledge in networking to setup distcc? how is your experience?

Comment: I have not actually used distcc in any project. Maybe tried, I don't remember. I used ccache, usually integrating such wrappers fir gcc are very straightforward - you substitute CC or some else variable in Makefile. If you are embedded engineer you should be familiar with custom compilers, it does not differ much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In gdb, you can do this:

[set substitute-path from to](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Source-Path.html#set-substitute_002dpath)

> Define a source path substitution rule, and add it at the end of the
>   current list of existing substitution rules. If a rule with the same
>   from was already defined, then the old rule is also deleted. For
>   example, if the file /foo/bar/baz.c was moved to /mnt/cross/baz.c,
>   then the command (gdb) set substitute-path /foo/bar /mnt/cross will
>   tell GDB to replace ‘/foo/bar’ with ‘/mnt/cross’, which will allow GDB
>   to find the file baz.c even though it was moved. In the case when more
>   than one substitution rule have been defined, the rules are evaluated
>   one by one in the order where they have been defined. The first one
>   matching, if any, is selected to perform the substitution. For
>   instance, if we had entered the following commands: (gdb) set
>   substitute-path /usr/src/include /mnt/include (gdb) set
>   substitute-path /usr/src /mnt/src GDB would then rewrite
>   /usr/src/include/defs.h into /mnt/include/defs.h by using the first
>   rule. However, it would use the second rule to rewrite
>   /usr/src/lib/foo.c into /mnt/src/lib/foo.c.